# How to automatics go on url address without clicking on it

Tags: javascript, html, url

I found the following script on the Internet.

How do I change the code so that when the `Open` button is clicked it will go to the address in `lnk.href` (`"https://www.google.si/maps/place/ljubljana" + userInput;`)

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText2(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
    lnk.href = "https://www.google.si/maps/place/ljubljana" + userInput;
    lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href; 
}
</script>
Type the location and click Open! <a href="" id=lnk>link</a> <br>
<input type='text' id='userInput' value='' />
<input type='submit' onclick='changeText2()' value='Open'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add `window.location = lnk.href;` at the end of your function:

```
<script>
function changeText2() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
    lnk.href = "https://www.google.si/maps/place/ljubljana" + userInput;
    lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href;
    window.location = lnk.href;
}
</script>

Type the location and click Open! <a href="" id=lnk>link</a> <br>
<input type='text' id='userInput' value='' />
<input type='submit' onclick='changeText2()' value='Open'/>
```

---

You can also do away with the link:

```
<script>
function openUrl() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    window.location = "https://www.google.si/maps/place/ljubljana" + userInput;
}
</script>

Type the location and click Open!<br>
<input type='text' id='userInput' value='' />
<input type='submit' onclick='openUrl()' value='Open' />
```